# How can I define custom route in HomeController of ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have an issue about defining a custom route in the HomeController of ASP.NET MVC.

When I submit the form, the route is defined as `Home/BlogSearch/?searchKeyword=Lorem`. However, I'd like to get this URL `/blogs/blogsearch?searchKeyword=text`.

Here is my form html part which is shown below.

```
<form action="/Home/BlogSearch/">
    <input type="text" name="searchKeyword" id="searchKeyword">
    <button type="submit" id="searchButton"><i class="bi bi-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

Here is my BlogSearch function which is defined in HomeController.

```
public ActionResult BlogSearch(string searchKeyword, int Sayfa = 1)
        {
            
            var searchList = db.Blog.Include("Kategori").Where(
                      x => x.Icerik.Contains(searchKeyword)
                      ).OrderByDescending(x => x.BlogId).ToPagedList(Sayfa, 5);

            return View(searchList);
        }
```

I wrote this route but it didn't work.

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "BlogSearch",
   url: "blogs/blogsearch",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "BlogSearch" }
);
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: The order in which you define your routes does matter - can you include the rest of the routes in your route config, as they exist in your RouteConfig.cs (or wherever you've defined your routes)?

Comment: @TiesonT. Is my route map which I wrote right?

Comment: It would work, but only if something else doesn't match a different pattern first (like the default route).

Comment: @TiesonT. I couldn't get this url `/blogs/blogsearch?searchKeyword=text`. Where is the problem in my map route?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is my solution shown below.

I changed the url which is defined below instead of `/Home/BlogSearch/`

```
<form action="/blogs/blogsearch">

</form>
```

Here is my BlogSearch method shown below with adding the custom `url`

```
[Route("blogs/blogsearch")]
public ActionResult BlogSearch(string searchKeyword, int Sayfa = 1)
        {
            
            var searchList = db.Blog.Include("Kategori").Where(
                      x => x.Icerik.Contains(searchKeyword)
                      ).OrderByDescending(x => x.BlogId).ToPagedList(Sayfa, 5);

            return View(searchList);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register a route in RouteConfig class, which is in RouteConfig.cs under the App_Start folder. Custom routes can be configured using the MapRoute extension method. You need to provide at least two parameters in the MapRoute function i.e. route name and URL pattern. The Default parameter is optional.

You can refer to this link: [Custom Routing in ASP.net MVC](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/custom-routing-asp-dot-net-mvc/#:%7E:text=Creating%20Custom%20Routes%20in%20ASP,custom%20routes%20with%20different%20names.)

Answer (score 0):

Try attribute routing:

```
[Route("~/blogs/blogsearch/{searchKeyword}/{sayfa?}")]
public ActionResult BlogSearch(string searchKeyword, int Sayfa = 1)
```

You will have to to use this url

```
url /blogs/blogsearch/searchText
```

if you still want to use this url

```
 url /blogs/blogsearch?searchKeyword=searchText
```

you can try

```
[Route("~/blogs/blogsearch")]
public ActionResult BlogSearch([FromQuery] string searchKeyword)
```

if you use routeconfig , you will have to add

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

your view

```
<form action="BlogSearch" controller="Blogs">
```

Comment: it didn't work. I couldn't get this url /blogs/blogsearch?searchKeyword=text. Where is the problem in my map route?

Comment: You should use this  - url /blogs/blogsearch/text.

Comment: I wrote thie url above BlogSearch function but it shows this url `https://localhost:44333/Home/BlogSearch/?searchKeyword=Lorem` after I submit the form. I already defined `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` in my `Routeconfig.cs` .How can I fix url link in form action?

Comment: You have to use url https://localhost:44333/Blogas/BlogSearch?searchKeyword=Lorem

Comment: You need a model to submit  a form.  What model do you use?